# How to do this on the tcsh shell in linux

Tags: linux, shell, tcsh

I want to efficiently do the following on the tcsh in Linux.

```
somecommand a;
somecommand b;
somecommand c;
```

If I do `somecommand {a,b,c}`, this does `somecommand a b c`, which is not what I want. Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

In tcsh, you should use a `foreach` loop, like this :

```
foreach val (a b c)
  somecommand $val
end
```

Better yet would be to have the values in a variable, like this :

```
set values="a b c"

foreach val ($values)
  somecommand $val
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bash, it's `for i in  a b c; do somecommand $i; done`.  I bet it's similar in tcsh.

Answer (score 0):

@Borealid's loop is best. Just for kicks, another way is to use xargs:

```
echo a b c | xargs -n 1 somecommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Boralid and John for your answers. I have created an alias in tcsh for this. It works!!

```
alias myglob 'echo \!:2-$ | xargs -n 1 \!:1'
```